# Using the same JavaScript on a different page, why am I getting an error?

Tags: javascript

I am using the same JavaScript that works flawlessly in one page in a second page, but I am getting an error in the second page. I didn't write the JavaScript and can't change it, so please help me figure out what is causing the error.

I tried moving the line of code that calls the JavaScript around, but that doesn't help. I checked the first page against the second page, but don't see anything that would make it stop working.

Calling the JavaScript here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/rating.min.js"></script>
```

The JavaScript code is:

```
!function(){
    "use strict";
    function t(t,i,n,e){
        function r(t,i){ 
            for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){
                var e=t[n];i(e,n)
            }
        }
        function a(t){
           s(t),o(t),u(t)
        }
        function s(t){
           t.addEventListener("mouseover",function(i){
               r(f,function(i,n){
                   n<=parseInt(t.getAttribute("data-index"))?i.classList.add("is-active"):i.classList.remove("is-active")
               })
           })
        }
        function o(t){
           t.addEventListener("mouseout",function(t){
             -1===f.indexOf(t.relatedTarget)&&c(null,!1)
           })
        }
        function u(t){
            t.addEventListener("click",function(i){
               i.preventDefault(),c(parseInt(t.getAttribute("data-index"))+1,!0)
            })
        }
        function c(t,a){
            t&&0>t||t>n||(void 0===a&&(a=!0),i=t||i,r(f,function(t,n){
                i>n?t.classList.add("is-active"):t.classList.remove("is-active")
            }),e&&a&&e(d()))
        }
        function d(){
            return i
        }
        var f=[];
        return function(){
            if(!t)throw Error("No element supplied.");
            if(!n)throw Error("No max rating supplied.");
            if(i||(i=0),0>i||i>n)throw Error("Current rating is out of bounds.");
            for(var e=0;n>e;e++){
                var r=document.createElement("li");
                r.classList.add("c-rating__item"),r.setAttribute("data-index",e),i>e&&r.classList.add("is-active"),t.appendChild(r),f.push(r),a(r)
            }
        }(),{
           setRating:c,getRating:d
        }
     }
     window.rating=t}();
```

The error I am getting is: `'Uncaught TypeError: t.appendChild is not a function.`

The code in the page:

```
echo 'Please rate the quality of this transcript:<br/>';
echo '<div style="height: 44px; padding: 5px;text-align: center;">';
echo '<span id="qualitystars" style="vertical-align: sub;"><li class="c-rating__item" data-index="0"></li><li class="c-rating__item" data-index="1"></li><li class="c-rating__item" data-index="2"></li><li class="c-rating__item" data-index="3"></li><li class="c-rating__item" data-index="4"></li> </span>';
echo '</div><input type="hidden" name="quality" id="quality">';
```

The original page didn't have the `<li>` hard coded, but for some reason I have to put those in or they don't show. Maybe that's somehow related to the error I'm getting?

What should appear is 5 outlines of stars and when a user hovers their mouse above a star, that star and those leading up to it from the left should be solid. The user can then click on a star to submit the rating.  Right now I see the outlines, but when I hover, only the star that I'm hovering over is solid.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** Here is where I call the rating:

```
let q_curr = 1;
let q_el = $('qualitystars');
let q_cb_rating = function (rating) {
    $('quality').value = rating;
};
let q_rating = rating(q_el, q_curr, 5, q_cb_rating);
```

It is calling the JavaScript file, which is rating.min.js.

Comment: Please format your JS, because it's very unreadable in minified version

Comment: Don't try to debug obfuscated code. Use readable code. Then reduce it to a [mcve].

Comment: The code comes like that. I tried to format it, but can't make head or tail of it, so I felt it was best to leave it as is.

Comment: the last echo line has no ' character at the end and there is one </div> too much

Comment: Also why not have the UL you are supposed to have instead of the span

Comment: Also please post a link to the actual rating plugin you are using

Comment: Also show where you initialise the rating

Comment: @mplungjan, the original page just had the `<span>` tags with nothing inside them and it worked. The only way I could get mine to appear was to hard code the `<li>` tags.

Comment: `The error I am getting is` - any good browser will also tell you exactly which line of code is producing the error ...

Comment: @JaromandaX, the error is in the .js file, but because the file was all clumped together on one line, it says the error is on line 1. It's near the end of the file, but all the code is one line.

Comment: You are missing the # in the selectors and the plugin expects a DOM element
`let q_el = $('#qualitystars')[0];`to get the DOM element - it is a UL without LIs: `<ul id="qualitystars" style="vertical-align: sub;"></ul>` AND `$('#quality').value = rating;`

Comment: @mplungjan, I can try that. I don't understand why the other page just has the `<span>` element and works fine, but the second page needs to be hard coded. Any idea?

Comment: Voting to close as `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.`

Comment: You should not use SPAN if the plugin adds LIs. the other page likely uses document.getElementById instead of the wrong `$('qualitystars')`

Comment: I copied the code from the one page to the other, so they both use the same code.

Comment: That is impossible because your code would never work `let q_el = $('qualitystars');` will NEVER work unless you have `<qualitystars></qualitystars>` in the HTML

Comment: I don't know what to say. The code works perfectly in the first page. I was told to copy the code to the second page, which I did, and it doesn't work in the second page.

Comment: The first page has different invocation and/or HTML. What can I say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the first page uses MooTools and the second page uses jQuery, which don't work together. I am rewriting the function for the second page using jQuery.

Thank you to everyone who responded.